# Meu client não consegue achar meu HttpServer?

Tags: java, http-request

Esse é o código do meu client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            SendData sender = new SendData();
            String JsonDeDados;
            String infos = "informacoes";

            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            CloseableHttpClient clientclose = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("localhost");
```

E esse do meu server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(5030), 0);
        System.out.println("Executando");
        server.createContext("/data", new dataHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
```

Eles não conseguem conversar... alguém pode me dar uma luz?
Sou iniciante!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, o erro é bem simples:

Tá vendo a linha:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("localhost");
```

?

Ela tem que ser alimentada com um pouco mais de informação.
Como você tá declarando no server >HTTP< a porta 5030, com o handler "/data" a resolução final fica:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:5030/data");
```

Espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: Era isso msm, mt obrigado. Coloquei e funcionou